# PHP/MYSQL convert array to WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

Convert this array

```
array("user_id"=>"8", "product_id"=>"35", "quantity"=>"1")
```

to query

```
select * from tbl_name where user_id='8' and product_id='35' and quantity='1'
```

And also how to use codeigniter active record function to php any way or library available ?

Comment: Have you tried something? Show us your code...

Comment: As mentioned above, you should show your code so that the community can point you back in the right direction; if you have not yet attempted any code, the following section of CodeIgniter's documentation may be of some use: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: im using implode funciton it is show message 'SELECT * FROM add_to_cart WHERE 8,35,1 ' but i need associate array

Comment: @Ben Broadley  i know that codeigniter active record  but i need all function like codeigniter to php,  any way there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [implode](http://php.net/implode) and [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

```
<?php
$where_arr = array("user_id"=>"8", "product_id"=>"35", "quantity"=>"1");
$where = implode(' AND ', array_map(function ($value, $key) { return "`". $key . "`='" . $value . "'"; }, $where_arr, array_keys($where_arr)));
```

OR [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
$where_arr = array("user_id"=>"8", "product_id"=>"35", "quantity"=>"1");
array_walk($where_arr, function (&$value, $key) { $value = "`". $key . "`='" . $value . "'"; });
$where = implode(' AND ', $where_arr );
```

Create query

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE '.$where;
```

`$query` output:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE `user_id`='8' AND `product_id`='35' AND `quantity`='1'
```

**CodeIgniter**

In your controller, get data

```
$where_arr = array("user_id"=>"8", "product_id"=>"35", "quantity"=>"1");
$results['products'] = $this->db->get_where('tbl_name', $where_arr)->result();

$this->load->view('your_view_name', $results);
```

Now you can use `$products` variable in your view, it has all found products.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$array  = array("user_id"=>"8","product_id"=>"35","quantity"=>"1");
$clauses = array();
foreach ($array as $field => $value) {
  $clauses[] = "$field='$value'";
}
$where_clause = join(" and ",$clauses);
echo "select * from tbl_name where " . $where_clause;
```